# How to get info from a third table when joining two tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have this schema:

[image]

- There is a table for persons.
- Each person has one "info" table.
- Persons can have friends. This is stored in another table called "friends", which has a foreign key for the person, and another one for his friend (both are pointing to the "person" table).

**"person" model:**

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :info
  has_many :friends
end
```

**"info" model:**

```
class Info < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person

  attr_accessible :description
end
```

**"friends" model:**

```
class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person

  attr_accessible :friend_id
end
```

Let's suppose we have 2 persons: person1 and person2. Each one with a record in the "info" table storing its description. And let's suppose that person2 is a friend of person1.

**content of "person" table:**

> id: 1
>
> id: 2

**content of "info" table:**

> id: 1, person_id: 1, description: "This is person 1, our main dude."
>
> id: 2, person_id: 2, description: "This is person 2, our secondary dude."

**content of "friends" table:**

> id: 1, person_id: 1, friend_id: 2

If I want to get person1's friends I do this:

```
Person.first.friends
```

This will give me:

> id: 1, person_id: 1, friend_id: 2

Now, how do I add the "info" content for each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the first solution I have come with:

```
Friends.select("p.description").joins("INNER JOIN info i ON i.person_id = friend_id").where(person_id: 1)
```

Anyone with a better/clearer/more efficient one?

Comment: For people searching for a more structured way, I recommend reading salt.racer's answer. I'm going to accept my answer as it is more optimized (it only makes 1 query) and does not need additional associations.

Comment: i'm not sure where the `p` in `p.description` came from? is this a complete statement?

Comment: @DavidMorales i found this more useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/29127164/3728916

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Rails built in "includes" query association feature?

From http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

It should be something like `Person.first.friends.includes(:info)`

Update: Ah, you want the Friends info, and there is no association on the model to get that right now.

It looks like you are missing an association to get the `Person` model for the friend (and not for the user). Something like:

```
class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :friendly_person, :class_name => "Person", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
end
```

Then you can use the associations you have set up with the includes similar to before `Person.first.friends.includes(:friendly_person => :info)` and that should return the info for the friend.

Another update: To access the info column for the `friendly_person` you can use the association. As in `friendly_person.info.description`. You can't do that on a collection (obviously) you have to have an instance of person. So something like `Person.first.friends.includes(:friendly_person => :info).first.friendly_person.info.description` ... but I would like to point out that this type of code is not considered to be good practice.

Comment: It throws this error: ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'info' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: For clarification, whose "info" content are you trying to get, the Person or the Friend?

Comment: Ok, that seems to be better. Now how could I access the description field from the Info table?

Comment: Wouldn't it be Person.first.friends.includes(:friendly_person => :info).first.info.description ?

Comment: I don't think so because there is no association between friends and info, except through the Person model so you need to get the friendly_person first. I recommend experimenting. You might be able to set up a has_one :through association following the rails guides.