# How to join an indirect association in ActiveRecord query in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

In my Ruby on Rails application, I have a model `Instance` which belongs to another model `Zone`. The `Zone` model itself belongs to `Country` model. I am fetching a set of `Instance` objects as follows:

```
scope :thisweek, -> { joins(:zone).where(zones: {created_at: ...}).includes(:zone)
```

I would like to join `Country` to `Zone` and `Instance` as well, and then sort the result `Instance` set based on the `zone.country.name` field. Anyone can help me please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use join query for 4 tables in rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29071052/how-to-use-join-query-for-4-tables-in-rails)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
scope :this_week, proc do
  includes(zone: :country)
    .where(zones: {created_at: whatever})
    .order('countries.name ASC')
end
```

(I used the `do/end` format on purpose to show on multi-lines each instruction)

---

Also, something you should know:

```
# if
Zone belongs_to :country
# then
Zone.includes(:country).where(countries: { id: 12 })
#                    ^               ^^
# but if
Zone has_many :countries
# then
Zone.includes(:countries).where(countries: { id: 12 })
#                     ^^               ^^
```

The `where` always uses the table's name but `includes`/`joins` uses the relation's name as it was declared in the model.

Comment: That extra bit you added at the end there was a real time saver. How confusing... though I'm sure there was a valid reason to design it this way.